# Staking more then 10 BZZ on Ethereum Swarm Bee node

Tags: ethereum, swarm

I am running the Ethereum Swarm Bee node, the minimum stake is 10 BZZ, what happens if I stake more than 10 BZZ?

For now, I am staking a minimum amount needed, 10 BZZ.

Answer (score 0):

10 BZZ is the minimum stake.  Staking more supposedly increases your node's chance of being selected as the "truth" in a given round and/or actually winning the round in your neighbourhood.